# pop() function of stack in C++ for a member of a class

Tags: c++, class, stack

It's been a while since I coded the last time in C++, but I'm currently stuck with a problem that I can't make sense off... Consider the following code

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

class test{
    private:
        std::stack<int> member;

    public:
        test(std::stack<int> u){
            while(!u.empty()){
                member.push(u.top());
                u.pop();
            }
        }

        int top_from_member(void){
            return member.top();
        }

        void pop_from_member(void){
            member.pop();
        }
};

int main(){
    std::stack<int> a;

    a.push(1);
    a.push(2);

    test b = test(a);
    std::cout << b.top_from_member() <<"\n";
    b.pop_from_member();
    std::cout << b.top_from_member() <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I just wrote a class that has a private member of type `stack` and wrote functions to get the top value and to pop a value. It works just as I hoped it would. Now consider in comparison to it the following code

```
#include <stack>
#include <iostream>

class test{
    private:
        std::stack<int> member;

    public:
        test(std::stack<int> u){
            while(!u.empty()){
                member.push(u.top());
                u.pop();
            }
        }

        int top_from_member(void){
            return member.top();
        }

        void pop_from_member(void){
            member.pop();
        }
};


class test2{
    private:
        test member2;
    public:
        test2 (test v) : member2(v){}

        test get_stack(void) const {
            return this->member2;
        }
};


int main(){
    std::stack<int> a;

    a.push(1);
    a.push(2);

    test2 b = test2(a);
    std::cout << b.get_stack().top_from_member() <<"\n";
    b.get_stack().pop_from_member();
    std::cout << b.get_stack().top_from_member() <<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is that I have now a second class that has a private member of type `test`. I wrote a function `get_stack` to be able to excess the stack from `test::member` and then again use `top_from_member` and `pop_from_member`. It seems that `top_from_member` works just fine, but `pop_from_member` doesn't do anything. Can somebody maybe explain why and how I would need to modify `pop_from_member` to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `b.get_stack()` to modify `b` because `test2::get_stack` is `const`. How are you expecting to modify `b` when you only call `const` functions on it?

In fact, `test2` has no non-`const` member functions, so there is absolutely no way to modify a `test2` object. Calling `get_stack()` is calling a `const` member function that, sensibly, provides no way to modify the object on which it is called.

Add a non-`const` member function that returns a modifiable reference or, better yet, add a pop function to `test2`.

Comment: Why would adding a `pop` function to `test2` be preferable to option one? It kind of seems strange to have the `pop` function in a different class than the `top` function..

Comment: @Sito Wouldn't it be strange to have the `pop` function in a different class than the `get_stack` function? But it's hard to tell what would be the most sensible API given that the class is a toy class, maybe looking at the real one would change my opinion.

Comment: That's a fair point.. Thank you for the help. Can you maybe explain why one must return a reference instead of a copy? I'm still a bit confused about that...

Comment: @Sito If you return a copy and the caller modifies the copy, the original is unchanged. If you return a reference to the original, the caller can modify the original.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning a copy of the stack. Try returning a reference instead.

```cpp
        const test& get_stack(void) const {
            return this->member2;
        }
```

Comment: He won't be able to call `pop_from_member` on the `const` reference that's returned.

Comment: Could you explain why returning a copy is no good? Your suggestion worked after considering what @DavidSchwartz wrote (aka removing the `const`)

Comment: Lets assume the internal stack has 1 element in it. You return a copy of that stack, and pop and element from it. Your copy is now empty, but the stack within the class still has one element in it. The copy will then drop out of scope at the end of the function, and be deleted. By returning a reference you are working on the member stack directly, rather than a copy of it.